# Change only width of collectionviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I am trying to make a collectionview with cells that changes width depending on the screensize. in iOS and swift. currently i am using th function "sizeForItemAtIndexPath". i can't just type in the height because i have diffrent type of cells in the storyboard with diffrent heights. so i want the heigth to be same but be able to change the width

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(changingWidth, sameHeight)
}
```

Comment: Do you reload you collection view on screen size change ?

Comment: yes, it's not that there is the problem. the problem is to get the cells height, so i can return it. it's because i have many different prototype cells, or whatever they are called, the ones you make in the storyboard. those cells have different height. so i can't just write 170 in "same height"

Answer (score 1):

**Swift**

I tried this and it worked for me:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var height:CGFloat = 10.0  // Fallback value
    if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        height = layout.itemSize.height
    }
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my first attempt, but I don't know the order of the calls -- this may set up infinite recursion or otherwise break your stuff:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        return CGSizeMake(changingWidth, cell.frame.height)
    } else {
        return CGSizeMake(changingWidth, defaultHeight)
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. it seems like sizeForItemAtIndexPath runs before cellForItemAtIndexPath so cellForItemAtIndexPath will always be nil. and if i update it the cells height would be the default height.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Drat!